# Document Type Does Not Allow Element Problems

Tags: html, css

I'm getting 100 errors when validating my site. I don't want to continue the build until I get this worked out. I've gone line-by-line and I'm not understanding why I have these issues. The rough draft start page is at www.flynntec.com. An example error:

> document type does not allow element "h3" here; assuming missing "li" start-tag [XHTML 1.0 Transitional]

or

> document type does not allow element "li" here; missing one of "ul", "ol", "menu", "dir" start-tag [XHTML 1.0 Transitional]

followed by

> The mentioned element is not allowed to appear in the context in which you've placed it; the other mentioned elements are the only ones that are both allowed there and can contain the element mentioned. This might mean that you need a containing element, or possibly that you've forgotten to close a previous element.
>
> One possible cause for this message is that you have attempted to put a block-level element (such as "<p>" or "<table>") inside an inline element (such as "<a>", "<span>", or "<font>").

Sample HTML:

```
<li class="menu_right"><a href="#" class="drop">Access</a>  

  <div class="dropdown_5columns align_right">

        <div class="col_5">  
          <h2>Microsoft Access</h2>  
        </div>  

        <div class="col_1">
        <img src="media/Access Logo.png" width="120" height="118" alt="Microsoft Access" />
         </div>  

        <div class="col_1">  
             <ul class="greybox"><h3>Beginner</h3><li><a href="#">Welcome to Access</a></li>  
                <li><a href="#">The Power of Access</a></li>  
                <li><a href="#">Intro to Databases</a></li>  
                <li><a href="#">Intro to Tables</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Creating Forms</a></li>  
                <li><a href="#">More...</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col_1">  
            <ul class="greybox"><h3>Intermediate</h3><li><a href="#">Custom Queries</a></li>  
                <li><a href="#">Create Reports</a></li>  
                <li><a href="#">Primary Key Guide</a></li>  
                <li><a href="#">Filtering Quickly</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">More...</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>  

        <div class="col_1">  
            <ul class="greybox"><h3>Advanced</h3><li><a href="#">Web Integration</a></li>  
                <li><a href="#">Advanced Forms</a></li>  
                <li><a href="#">Using Triggers</a></li>  
                <li><a href="#">Shortcuts</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Expression Builder</a></li>  
                <li><a href="#">More...</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>  

        <div class="col_5">  
            <h2>Additional Free Resources</h2>  
        </div>  

        <div class="col_3">  

            <img src="media/youtube-logo.jpg" alt="YouTube Picture" name="youtube" width="90" height="70" class="img_left imgshadow" id="youtube_logo_2" />  
            <p>Microsoft Access is an ideal small-business database engine. YouTube is a great source for Access guides. We have compiled the best, most popular Access tutorials from YouTube and put them here for your convenience. </p>  

          <br />
          <a href="http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/training-FX101782702.aspx" target="_blank"><img src="media/microsoft-logo__111129012732.jpg" alt="" name="microsoft" width="90" height="24" class="img_left imgshadow" id="microsoft_logo_2" /></a>  
            <p><a href="http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/training-FX101782702.aspx"  title="Microsoft Training" target="_blank">Microsoft has fantastic resources on their  website. Microsoft Training can be found here.</a></p>
</div>
</div>
</li>
```

Yes, there are opening and closing UL's.

Comment: Why the XHTML strict doctype? Is it necessary? Can you just use the HTML5 doctype <!DOCTYPE html>?

Comment: I never considered it -- what's the proper syntax to use?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html> <-- put this as the first line, where your current doctype is.

Comment: That won't help; this is invalid HTML5 too.

Comment: Next time you encounter an error like this, try to read the HTML specification. It is clearly defined that an `ul` can only contain `li` elements.

Comment: @micha - No. only li elements.

Comment: @micha - The ul must go inside an li. i.e. http://jsfiddle.net/F3E7p/1/ is the only valid way.

Answer (score 4):

Some HTML elements can only contain certain other HTML elements. An UL can only contain LI elements, so a H3 inside an UL is an error.
Either move the H3 out of the UL, or put it inside a LI.
What effect are you trying to achieve?

Also, even though your webpage thinks it's XHTML Transitional, you are serving it up with a `text/html` MIME type, so the browsers will treat it as HTML.
If you really want XHTML, make sure the MIME type is `application/xhtml+xml`. But then older versions of IE won't display it.

Comment: The H3 has a border-bottom that causes Beginner to have a nice looking line underneath it when mousing over any of the menu bar.

Comment: @jdflynn55 I am sure there are around 10 other ways to achieve the same line.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have a h3 element directly inside ul - it needs to be within an li, or before the ul - that should already fix the majority of the validation errors...

Answer (score 2):

As the error clearly states, your HTML is invalid.

`<ul>`s can only (directly) contain `<li>`s.

Answer (score 2):

`<ul>` tag is for placing only `<li>` tags inside, why don't you put that `<h3>` before `<ul>` elements?

Answer (score 1):

XHTML Transitional is complaining because you have an `<h3>` directly inside of your `<ul>`, without containing it in a `<li>`. This actually is bad practice.

```
<ul class="greybox"><h3>Beginner</h3><li><a href="#">Welcome to Access</a></li>  
                <li><a href="#">The Power of Access</a></li>  
                <li><a href="#">Intro to Databases</a></li>  
                <li><a href="#">Intro to Tables</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Creating Forms</a></li>  
                <li><a href="#">More...</a></li>
          </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have h3's directly inside ul's for a start. They need to be outside the list, our inside an li.